# Trying to create two columns with no NULL value and now duplicates in id col

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-synapse

I am trying to get 2 dates, for 2 different activities PER ONE referral number. The dates for these activities is stored in a `CustomerHistory` table.

My goal is to get 1 row per referral number, and two separate columns, showing the activity dates.

When of the activities does not have a date --> blank cell, but again I want to have 1 row per referral number.

With the current code I get a duplicated row per referral number, when both activities have dates:

```
SELECT 
    r.Reference, 
    CASE
        WHEN ch.NoteAction = 'Activity2' 
            THEN ch.zu_creationTimeStamp_um
    END AS 'Action_Activity2',
    CASE
        WHEN ch.NoteAction = 'Activity1' 
            THEN ch.zu_creationTimeStamp_um
    END AS 'Action_Activity1', 
    -- ch.zu_creationTimeStamp_um,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ch.id_Contact, ch.NoteAction ORDER BY ch.zu_creationTimeStamp_um DESC) AS 'row_num' 
FROM 
    hug2.ReferralUpdates r 
LEFT JOIN 
    hug2.CustomerHistory ch ON r.Reference = ch.id_Contact 
WHERE 
    ch.NoteAction = 'Activity2'
    OR ch.NoteAction = 'Activity1'
```

This returns:

| Ref Num | Activity1 | Activity2 | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 107971 | 2024-01-22 | (NULL) | 1 |
| 107971 | (NULL) | 2024-01-20 | 1 |
| 155666 | (NULL) | 2024-02-02 | 1 |
| 155666 | 2024-01-10 | (NULL) | 1 |

When what I need to have is:

| Ref Num | Activity1 | Activity2 | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 107971 | 2024-01-22 | 2024-01-20 | 1 |
| 155666 | 2024-01-10 | 2024-02-02 | 1 |

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Sample data should be provided as DDL and DML statements, and anything else as a well formatted markdown table.

Comment: Aren't you just after the `MAX` value..?

Comment: Hi, I will try to update the post, and fix the tables.
No, I am not after the MAX value of them two, I want to check for each referral number, what is the date for Activity1, if Activity1 have taken place at all, and what is the date for Activity 2. My problem is that when a referral number has 2 of these dates I get 2 rows per the referral, when I need to have 1 rows per referral, and a date in each column, if both activities have happened

Comment: Seems, from your sample data, `MAX` is exactly what you want. The `MAX` of `2024-01-22` and `NULL` is `2024-01-22`, so that'd the value you'd get, not `NULL`.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data in the two tables shown in your query, it will be much easier to replicate your current issue with this. If you can supply a script to create the table and sample values, even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like :

```
SELECT r.Reference, 
       ch1.zu_creationTimeStamp_um AS 'Action_Activity1',
       ch2.zu_creationTimeStamp_um AS 'Action_Activity2', 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY r.Reference, ch1.NoteAction ORDER BY ch1.zu_creationTimeStamp_um DESC) AS 'row_num' 
FROM   hug2.ReferralUpdates r 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN hug2.CustomerHistory ch1 
          ON r.Reference = ch1.id_Contact AND  ch1.NoteAction = 'Activity1'
       LEFT OUTER JOIN hug2.CustomerHistory ch2 
          ON r.Reference = ch2.id_Contact AND  ch2.NoteAction = 'Activity2';
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mention in the comments, you just need a `MAX` here. For your sample data, this would simply be the following:

```sql
SELECT V.[Ref Num],
       MAX(V.Activity1) AS Activity1,
       MAX(V.Activity2) AS Activity2,
       V.rn
FROM (VALUES (107971, '2024-01-22', NULL, 1),
             (107971, NULL, '2024-01-20', 1),
             (155666, NULL, '2024-02-02', 1),
             (155666, '2024-01-10', NULL, 1)) V ([Ref Num], Activity1, Activity2, rn) --Don't use column names that require delimit  identifying
GROUP BY V.[Ref Num],
         V.rn;
```

If we take your query, this will presumably look like this (can't test, as no sample data for 2 tables):

```sql
WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT r.Reference,
            CASE WHEN ch.NoteAction = 'Activity2' THEN ch.zu_creationTimeStamp_um END AS Action_Activity2, --Don't use single quotes for aliases
            CASE WHEN ch.NoteAction = 'Activity1' THEN ch.zu_creationTimeStamp_um END AS Action_Activity1,
            -- ch.zu_creationTimeStamp_um,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ch.id_Contact,
                                            ch.NoteAction
                               ORDER BY ch.zu_creationTimeStamp_um DESC) AS row_num
     FROM hug2.ReferralUpdates r
         JOIN hug2.CustomerHistory ch ON r.Reference = ch.id_Contact --Due to your WHERE this is an INNER JOIN, so i've changed it to one.
     WHERE ch.NoteAction = 'Activity2'
        OR ch.NoteAction = 'Activity1')
SELECT V.[Ref Num],
       MAX(V.Activity1) AS Activity1,
       MAX(V.Activity2) AS Activity2,
       V.rn
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Reference,
         row_num;
```

I use a CTE as I don't know what the values of `id_Contact`, `NoteAction` and `zu_creationTimeStamp_um` are and they are completely omitted from your question, so I can't know if they can go in the `GROUP BY` or not.